# I'm stuck on my Android program

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I'm doing a maritime forescast program. Right know I have implemented the ListView with the places, the onListItemClick and the AsyncTask for get the data.

So now when I press in a place, I have such information as wind speed or direction in arrays windSpeed, windDir.....

Here is the point where I am stuck. Now that I have the data, I want that the list of places disappear and show a new window with the information by day.

I guess that I have to implement a new class that make a table view and switch to it by intent. But.. how can I pass the arrays in the main activity to this second activity? Because with putExtra I can only pass a value not an array no?

Comment: You don't need a new Activity. Just *setContentView()* with the new screen (you can have as many as you want on your *layout* folder).

Comment: No, he should start a new Activity. I hestitate to say never, but really, you should never call setContentView() more than once in an Activity -- it's just asking for trouble. Besides, this is supposed to appear on an item click, so it makes sense to keep it in the history stack so that the user can just press back to go back to the list of places.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely pass an array, take a look at:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html